# Counting number of items in an array, ignoring duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a JavaScript function which is capable of counting the number of unique items in an array (i.e. ignoring duplicates). For example,

```
var r = [car, car, bike, bike, truck]
```

The result should be 3 instead of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var r = ['car', 'car', 'bike', 'bike', 'truck'];
var counts = [], count = 0, i = 0;
for(i=0; i<r.length; i++) {
    if(counts[r[i]] == undefined) {
        counts[r[i]] = 1;
        count++;
    }
}
console.log(count);
```

For a given array, this prints the number of *unique* elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.count_unique = function() {
    var arr2 = [];
    for (i = this.length; i--;) {
        if (arr2.indexOf( this[i] ) == -1) arr2.push( this[i] );
    }
    return arr2.length;
}
```

used

```
var r      = ['car', 'car', 'bike', 'bike', 'truck'],
    unique = r.count_unique();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2h3Q8/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var arr = ['car', 'car', 'bike', 'bike', 'truck'],
    countUniques = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index == self.indexOf(elem);
}).length;
alert(countUniques); //will show 3
```

If you want it to be appliable to all Arrays:

```
Array.prototype.countUniques = function() {
    return this.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
        return index == self.indexOf(elem);
    }).length;
};
```

Usage: `arr.countUniques() // 3`